# extracting letters from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an array of strings denoting variants of shirts in my store. 
Here is an example string:

> Apparel-DTG-Tshirt-District-DT6000-M-Black-Mens-CF-20200304113232677

All of the strings share same structure and the rule that I need to implement is, extract what's in between 5th and 6th occurrence of - (dash). In this particular case this is M.
How do I do that?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Just split it at the `-` character, and pick the 6th element out of the resulting array …?

Comment: this is really trivial: `console.log("Apparel-DTG-Tshirt-District-DT6000-M-Black-Mens-CF-20200304113232677".split("-")[5])`

Answer (score 1):

This would help you. The first capturing group will be the value between fifth and sixth dash:

https://regex101.com/r/UlQBqy/2

```js
const re = /^(?:[^-]*-){5}(.*?)(?=-)/

console.log("Apparel-DTG-Tshirt-District-DT6000-M-Black-Mens-CF-20200304113232677".match(re)[1])
```